# How to correctly configure nova-compute to use FlatDHCPManager

Tags: 14.04, networking, juju, maas, nova

I am trying to deploy `Openstack` using `FlatDHCPManager`.  I am using **MAAS+Juju** to deploy all of my nodes (HP Moonshot) running trusty.

I want `eth1` to be the public interface.

Here are the relevant parts of my configuration yaml:

```
nova-cloud-controller:
  network-manager: 'FlatDHCPManager'
nova-compute:
  config-flags: 'public_interface=br100'
  flat-interface: eth0
  multi-host: 'yes'
  virt-type: kvm
```

I have tried setting flat-interface to both `eth0` and `eth1`.  I have tried specifying public_interface to be = eth1, br100, and not setting anything at all to take the default value.

Using the `config` settings shown above, I can `SSH` into a running VM *ONLY* from the nova-compute host that the VM is running on.  Otherwise, I can't get to it.

Once I `SSH` into the VM, I can't get out to anything.

I know most things are moving to Neutron, but that's not an option yet for what I am working with.  I need to stick with nova-network for a while.

I have seen articles/[bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1326345) and am not sure if the problem is related or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you reviewed the corresponding charm config options for flat networking in nova-compute? http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openstack-charmers/charms/trusty/nova-compute/trunk/view/head:/config.yaml#L89

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the following configuration now, and it is working:

```
nova-cloud-controller:
  network-manager: 'FlatDHCPManager'
nova-compute:
  config-flags: 'public_interface=juju-br0'
  flat-interface: eth0
  multi-host: 'yes'
  virt-type: kvm
```

This is necessary because of the juju-created bridge that is already on `eth0`, and prevents another bridge from being created.